# Count words in a string

Tags: java, performance, object-oriented, programming-challenge, unit-testing

Continuing my TDD from [exercism](http://exercism.io/exercises/java/word-count/readme).

> Write a program that given a phrase can count the occurrences of each word in that phrase.
>
> For example for the input `"olly olly in come free"`
>
> ```
> olly: 2
> in: 1
> come: 1
> free: 1
> ```

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

/**
 * Counts the word in a given string. Ignores any punctuation.
 * Example:
 *    "one two, two# ??three" === {"one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 1}
 */
public class WordCount {
  private final Map<String, Integer> wordFrequencyMap;

  WordCount() {
    wordFrequencyMap = new HashMap<>();
  }

  public Map<String, Integer> phrase(String phrase) {
    for (String word : phrase.trim().split("\\s+")) {
      word = withoutPunctuation(word.toLowerCase());
      if (word == null || word.isEmpty()) {
        continue;
      }
      if (!wordFrequencyMap.containsKey(word)) {
        wordFrequencyMap.put(word, 1);
      } else {
        wordFrequencyMap.put(word, wordFrequencyMap.get(word) + 1);
      }
    }
    return wordFrequencyMap;
  }

  private String withoutPunctuation(String word) {
    String wordWithoutPunctuation = "";
    for (char ch : word.toCharArray()) {
      if (isLetter(ch) || isDigit(ch)) {
        wordWithoutPunctuation += ch;
      }
    }
    return wordWithoutPunctuation;
  }

  private boolean isLetter(char ch) {
    return ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z';
  }

  private boolean isDigit(char ch) {
    return ch >= '0' && ch <= '9';
  }
}
```

Test suite:

```
import org.junit.Test;

import java.lang.Integer;
import java.lang.String;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class WordCountTest {

    private final WordCount wordCount = new WordCount();

    @Test
    public void countOneWord() {
        Map<String, Integer> actualWordCount = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        final Map<String, Integer> expectedWordCount = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        expectedWordCount.put("word", 1);

        actualWordCount = wordCount.phrase("word");
        assertEquals(
            expectedWordCount, actualWordCount
        );
    }

    @Test
    public void countOneOfEach() {
        Map<String, Integer> actualWordCount = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        final Map<String, Integer> expectedWordCount = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        expectedWordCount.put("one", 1);
        expectedWordCount.put("of", 1);
        expectedWordCount.put("each", 1);

        actualWordCount = wordCount.phrase("one of each");
        assertEquals(
            expectedWordCount, actualWordCount
        );
    }

    @Test
    public void countMultipleOccurences() {
        Map<String, Integer> actualWordCount = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        final Map<String, Integer> expectedWordCount = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        expectedWordCount.put("one", 1);
        expectedWordCount.put("fish", 4);
        expectedWordCount.put("two", 1);
        expectedWordCount.put("red", 1);
        expectedWordCount.put("blue", 1);

        actualWordCount = wordCount.phrase("one fish two fish red fish blue fish");
        assertEquals(
            expectedWordCount, actualWordCount
        );
    }

    @Test
    public void ignorePunctuation() {
        Map<String, Integer> actualWordCount = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        final Map<String, Integer> expectedWordCount = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        expectedWordCount.put("car", 1);
        expectedWordCount.put("carpet", 1);
        expectedWordCount.put("as", 1);
        expectedWordCount.put("java", 1);
        expectedWordCount.put("javascript", 1);

        actualWordCount = wordCount.phrase("car : carpet as java : javascript!!&@$%^&");
        assertEquals(
            expectedWordCount, actualWordCount
        );

    }

    @Test
    public void includeNumbers() {
        Map<String, Integer> actualWordCount = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        final Map<String, Integer> expectedWordCount = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        expectedWordCount.put("testing", 2);
        expectedWordCount.put("1", 1);
        expectedWordCount.put("2", 1);

        actualWordCount = wordCount.phrase("testing, 1, 2 testing");
        assertEquals(
            expectedWordCount, actualWordCount
        );
    }

    @Test
    public void normalizeCase() {
        Map<String, Integer> actualWordCount = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        final Map<String, Integer> expectedWordCount = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        expectedWordCount.put("go", 3);

        actualWordCount = wordCount.phrase("go Go GO");
        assertEquals(
            expectedWordCount, actualWordCount
        );
    }

}
```

Learning from my previous experiences I agree the code breaks encapsulation as an exception (client requirement). Other thing is that I didn't want to use Regex hence wanted to test my own knowledge.

Regarding performance I haven't thought much it should be O(n).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Building Strings with `+=`

In your `withoutPunctuation` method, you are building the String to return by appending each character with `+=`.

```
private String withoutPunctuation(String word) {
  String wordWithoutPunctuation = "";
  for (char ch : word.toCharArray()) {
    if (isLetter(ch) || isDigit(ch)) {
      wordWithoutPunctuation += ch;
    }
  }
  return wordWithoutPunctuation;
}
```

[It would be better](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18453485/1743880) to use a [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) which is a class dedicated for that. The problem is that each character will be turned into a `String` and concatenated to the previous `String`, resulting in a new `String` again and again. All those `String` creation takes time. Using a `StringBuilder` solves that problem:

```
private String withoutPunctuation(String word) {
    StringBuilder wordWithoutPunctuation = new StringBuilder();
    for (char ch : word.toCharArray()) {
        if (isLetter(ch) || isDigit(ch)) {
            wordWithoutPunctuation.append(ch);
        }
    }
    return wordWithoutPunctuation.toString();
}
```

#### Unnecessary checks

The String returned by the `withoutPunctuation` method can never be `null` (and that's a good thing). So there is no need to check for it later:

```
word = withoutPunctuation(word.toLowerCase());
if (word == null || word.isEmpty()) {
  continue;
}
```

You can just have:

```
word = withoutPunctuation(word.toLowerCase());
if (word.isEmpty()) {
    continue;
}
```

#### Potential bugs

You are currently lowercasing Strings with

```
word.toLowerCase()
```

This can lead to weird bugs. In fact, if someone with a Turkish locale were to run your code on the sentence `"I LIKE JAVA"`, they would have as result the map `{java=1, lke=1}`. Notice the `"I"` that are missing. This is because [changing the case of a String depends on the locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063102/using-locales-with-javas-tolowercase-and-touppercase) and by default, this is the locale of the JVM, which also defaults to your system locale. The capital `"I"` in Turkish is lowercased to `"ı"` (dot-less `i`), which then doesn't pass your filter because it isn't a character between `'a'` and `'z'`.

To counteract this, it is best to use the [`ROOT`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#ROOT) locale when changing the case, so you should have:

```
word.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT)
```

#### Cache the `Pattern`

Compiling a regulax expression `Pattern`, which is done internally by `split`, takes time. It would be best to compile it only once and reuse the `Pattern`. Consider making it a constant:

```
private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\s+");
```

Then you can have

```
for (String word : PATTERN.split(phrase.trim())) {
    // ...
}
```

#### Other comments

Do you really need `wordFrequencyMap` as an instance field? It is only used inside the `phrase` method so it would be better to declare it inside.

If you're on Java 8, consider using the Stream API for the `phrase` method. You would have:

```
public Map<String, Long> phrase(String phrase) {
    return PATTERN.splitAsStream(phrase.trim())
                  .map(s -> withoutPunctuation(s.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT)))
                  .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
                  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s, Collectors.counting()));
}
```

In the same way, the `withoutPunctuation` method can be written

```
private String withoutPunctuation(String word) {
    return word.chars()
               .filter(ch -> isLetter((char) ch) || isDigit((char) ch))
               .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append)
               .toString();
}
```

Comment: So `Locale.ROOT` would let me treat string as `English` irrespective of the locale we are in, right?

Comment: I think I need to start using java8, it seems cool.

Comment: @CodeYogi Not strictly, `ROOT` is the *language/country neutral locale for the locale sensitive operations*. Using `ENGLISH` would have the same effect here (I guess [it is a matter of taste](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10336730/which-locale-should-i-specify-when-i-call-string-tolowercase))

Comment: Really the `Locale` thing was new to me, thanks!

Comment: One more thing I would like to ask. I am preparing for the competitive programming and most of the books on algorithms I have read use the imperative style of coding, while the functional approach is a declarative one, what should I do? should I stick to java7 for the sake of getting correct material or move to java8 but then I think it would be difficult to get any good reference material.

Comment: Also, it seems too difficult to analyze the complexity of the algorithm in the functional style or I am not able to see it.

Comment: @CodeYogi Note that the imperative style of coding is still widely used in Java 8 ;). Not every task is appropriate for the Stream API: it really depends on the kind of algorithm. As starters, you might want to stick with goold-old `for` loops and look up [the Stream tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/index.html) for what kind of operation it is designed.

Comment: Regarding using Streams in competitive coding, make sure you check with the competition organizers for what version of Java you will be using. Recently I did a competition where I studied Streams a ton to prepare, and then got handed Java 6 in the event. Hope you win!

Answer (score 6):

#### Checking letters and digits

Instead of your own `isLetter` and `isDigit` methods,
it would be better to use `Character.isLetter` and `Character.isDigit`.
Even better, there's actually `Character.isLetterOrDigit` too.

#### Not using regular expressions

Although you say you don't want to use regular expressions, you're actually using them, in the `split`.

#### Performance

Note that when you split, an array is created from the String, roughly doubling the extra storage needed. You could reduce the storage by tokenizing manually.

It's not a huge problem, but in this code, if the `word` is in the map, you perform two lookups, first with `containsKey`, and then again with `get`:

> ```
>   if (!wordFrequencyMap.containsKey(word)) {
>     wordFrequencyMap.put(word, 1);
>   } else {
>     wordFrequencyMap.put(word, wordFrequencyMap.get(word) + 1);
>   }
> ```

Example alternative implementation:

```
public Map<String, Integer> phrase(String phrase) {
    Map<String, Integer> wordFrequencyMap = new HashMap<>();

    int start = indexOfWordStart(phrase, 0);
    while (start < phrase.length()) {
        int end = indexOfWordEnd(phrase, start);
        String word = phrase.substring(start, end).toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT);
        Integer count = wordFrequencyMap.get(word);
        if (count == null) {
            wordFrequencyMap.put(word, 1);
        } else {
            wordFrequencyMap.put(word, count + 1);
        }
        start = indexOfWordStart(phrase, end);
    }
    return wordFrequencyMap;
}

private int indexOf(String phrase, int start, Predicate<Character> predicate) {
    for (int i = start; i < phrase.length(); ++i) {
        if (predicate.test(phrase.charAt(i))) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return phrase.length();
}

protected int indexOfWordStart(String phrase, int start) {
    return indexOf(phrase, start, Character::isLetterOrDigit);
}

protected int indexOfWordEnd(String phrase, int start) {
    return indexOf(phrase, start, c -> !Character.isLetterOrDigit(c));
}
```

#### Unit tests

The unit tests are a bit tedious.
Take for example this test:

> ```
> Map<String, Integer> actualWordCount = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
> final Map<String, Integer> expectedWordCount = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
> expectedWordCount.put("word", 1);
>
> actualWordCount = wordCount.phrase("word");
> assertEquals(
>     expectedWordCount, actualWordCount
> );
> ```

This can be written in a single line:

```
assertEquals(Collections.singletonMap("word", 1), wordCount.phrase("word"));
```

But let's take a more interesting example:

> ```
> Map<String, Integer> actualWordCount = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
> final Map<String, Integer> expectedWordCount = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
> expectedWordCount.put("one", 1);
> expectedWordCount.put("of", 1);
> expectedWordCount.put("each", 1);
>
> actualWordCount = wordCount.phrase("one of each");
> assertEquals(
>     expectedWordCount, actualWordCount
> );
> ```

Can be shortened to:

```
final Map<String, Integer> expectedWordCount = new HashMap<>();
expectedWordCount.put("one", 1);
expectedWordCount.put("of", 1);
expectedWordCount.put("each", 1);

assertEquals(expectedWordCount, wordCount.phrase("one of each"));
```

The changes:

- There's really no need for `actualWordCount`, can be easily inlined without hurting readability

  - If you still want to keep `actualWordCount`, at least declare it right before you use it, not at the top of the method
- Use the diamond operator `<>`, so `new HashMap<>()` instead of `new HashMap<String, Integer>()`

Comment: The problem with `Character.isDigit` for example is that it will return `true` for all [Unicode character in the Nd category](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm), not just `'a-z'` which might be too much here (it depends on what is wanted).

Comment: Usually I don't look at test cases since its already there by exercism team but I think you are right they need to put some more effort. Regarding syntax it seems a bit alien to me like `Character::isLetterOrDigit`, is this java 8?

Comment: Yes that's Java 8

Comment: I need few more insights. 1) What is the use case of such class in which we really don't need any instance variables, should it be better as utility class with private constructor? 2) why `++i`?

Comment: Yes, a class with pure functions and no data can be turned into a utility class. For your second question, in this context `++i` and `i++` are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Since regular expression matching is so blazing fast I would use them to implement `withoutPunctuation()`:

```
private String withoutPunctuation(String s) {
    return s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s]+", "");
}
```

It would be even better to use pre-compiled regular expressions:

```
private static final Pattern ALPHANUMERIC_AND_SPACE_ONLY =
    Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s]+");

private String withoutPunctuation(String s) {
    return ALPHANUMERIC_AND_SPACE_ONLY.matcher(s).replaceAll("");
}
```

Of course you should benchmark it to see whether it's actually faster.